# Converts ArrayList into a sorted set (TreeSet) and returns it

Tags: java, arraylist

I a method that takes a list of numbers (e.g. `ArrayList`) and converts it into a sorted set (e.g. `TreeSet`) and returns it. I wrote code, but I'm having some problems.

```
public TreeSet getSort (ArrayList list){
   TreeSet set =new TreeSet(list);
    return set;
```

My problem is in main:

```
ArrayList List = new ArrayList();
    List.add(5);
    List.add(55);
    List.add(88);
    List.add(555);
    List.add(154);
    System.out.println("the TreeSet of ArrayList is : " + getSort(List));
```

Comment: Gives me an error in the the print statment

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You need to have the class instance to call the `getSort()` method or make the `getSort()` to `static`

Do like

```
System.out.println("the TreeSet of ArrayList is : "+ new classname().getSort(List));
```

or make the method static

```
    public static TreeSet getSort (ArrayList list){
       TreeSet set =new TreeSet(list);
        return set;
         }
```

Answer (score 2):

You're probably getting an error because `getSort()` isn't `static`, so it can't be called from `main()`. Beyond this, you shouldn't use [raw types](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/generics/rawTypes.html), parametrize your lists and sets:

```
ArrayList<Integer> list = ...

TreeSet<Integer> set = ...
```

You should be getting warnings about this.

In fact, I would make this method totally [generic](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/generics/):

```
public static <V extends Comparable<V>> TreeSet<V> getSort(List<V> list) {
    return new TreeSet<>(list);
}
```

Lastly, remember to follow naming conventions: local variable names should start with a lowercase letter (i.e. `list` and not `List`).

Comment: It would be a bit be generic to accept `List<V>` - not `ArrayList<V>`.

Comment: Or, actually, `Collection<V>`.

Answer (score 1):

`getSort()` isn't static and can't be called from main. You need to make it static.